# Created class has a mistake. Help to find it, pls)

Tags: php

I'm studying php and one of tasks was to create a certain class. I've tried a lot, but there is still error.

TASK:

> Create class `User`, that will have `$name` and `$age` private properties and public `$site` property, which values should be set in a class constructor, method `getFullInfo()`, that will return (not print!) `$this->name at the age of $this->age is a user of $this->site`. Constructor should check input age, and if it is greater than `130` or less than `0` set `$age` value as `unset` (just as a string). After successfully instance creation constructor should print `User was successfully created!`.

I use PHP 5.

Site, where i study, doesn't apply my version of solution.
Hope, u will help me ^^

```
<?php 
class User{
    private $name;
    private $age;
    public $site;
    function __construct($q,$w,$e){
        echo "User was successfully created!";
        $this->name=$q;
        $this->site=$e;
        if($w>130 || $w<0){
            unset($w);
        };
        $this->age=$w;
    }
    public function getFullInfo(){
        return "$this->name at the age of $this->age is a user of $this->site";
    } 
} 
?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by site does not apply your version.

Comment: I'm studying on online web development course, where syntax is described and then  exercise is given. My answer (written code) is wrong, so i want to find a mistake) Sorry for my inaccuracy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task says that if the age is out of range, you should set it to the string `unset`. Calling `unset($w)` doesn't do that. Change that to:

```
$w = "unset";
```

Comment: Thank u very much))

Answer (score 0):

You're close. Name your variables, arguments, and parameters something meaningful.

> if it is greater than 130 or less than 0 set $age value as unset (just
>   as a string)

Probably means `$this->age = 'unset';`

```
<?php 
class User
{
    private $name;
    private $age;
    public $site;

    function __construct($name, $site, $age)
    {
        echo "User was successfully created!";

        $this->name = $name;
        $this->site = $site;

        if ($age > 130 || $age < 0) {
            $this->age = 'unset';
        } else {
            $this->age = $age;
        }

    }

    public function getFullInfo()
    {
        return "$this->name at the age of $this->age is a user of $this->site";
    }
}

$user = new User('Tony McTony', 'Tree House', 35);

echo $user->getFullInfo();

// Output: User was successfully created!Tony McTony at the age of 35 is a user of Tree House
```

Comment: I understood)) Thanks a lot ^^

Answer (score 0):

I think it here:

```php
 return "$this->name at the age of $this->age is a user of $this->site";

// it should be : (i think)

return $this->name . "at the age of " . $this->age . " is a user of " . $this->site;
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

Most likely your problem is the unsetting of the `$w` variable. When they say unset the variable, you should do so to the `$this->age` rather than the `$w`.

```
<?php
$this->age = $w;
if($w > 130 || $w < 0){
   $this->age = 'unset';
};
?>
```

If this doesn't solve your problem then a more descriptive explanation of the problem would be helpful.

Comment: You should read the description more carefully. If the age is out of range it should be set to a string 'unset'.

Comment: You realize that unset is a function, it's a reasonable mistake

Comment: I do realize that, that doesn't change the fact that you should read the description more carefully if you make it an answer.